# After successful API, call back is not properly called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator

```
handleSubmit = ev => {

     ev.preventDefault();
     this.props.stripe.createToken().then(payload => {
       let data = {
            currency: 'USD',
            amount: localStorage.getItem("price"),
            source: payload.token.id,
            description: 'xyz'
        }
        PlanAction._stripecharge(data, function(data){

            let data1 = {
                username: localStorage.getItem('username'),
                plan: {
                    id: this.props.request.id,
                    planName: this.props.request.planName,
                    planType: this.props.request.planType
                    }

            }
            data.paid ? PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1) : null
        });

    });
 }
```

After successfull Stripe Charge, 
I am getting response as paid: true

If paid is true I am making use of ternary operator

```
data.paid  ? PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1) : null
```

Is this wrong?
why PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1) is not getting called may I know whats wrong in this

```
export function _stripecharge(data,callback) {
let url = "/charges";
 let BASE = "https://api.stripe.com/v1"
 let actualurl = BASE + url;

 stripeApi._callAPI(actualurl, 'POST', data, (type, dt) => {
     if (type == 'success') {
        dispatcher.dispatch({
            type: 'SnackBar',
            string: "Payment Success" 
        })

        callback(dt);

     } 

 });

}
```

Comment: try a `console.log(data)` in your `PlanAction._stripecharge` method see what is it

Comment: Hi! *"Response of PlanAction._stripecharge(data) is"* The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put the necessary details **in** the question, not just linked. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have edited with mocky resposne pleas echeck it

Comment: data.paid == "true" ? PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1) : null // you are checking it "true" instead of true

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing `data.paid` is `true`, not `"true"`, so with minimal changes:

```
data.paid ? PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1) : null
```

But seriously, this is what the `if` statement is for:

```
if (data.paid) PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1);
```

---

Side note: You're neither handling errors from `this.props.stripe.createToken()` nor passing the promise on to the caller. You must do one or the other. Based on the fact this looks like a DOM event handler, you'd want to handle errors (e.g., via `.catch`), not pass the promise on.

Comment: no,still i cannot able to call
PlanAction._createUserPlan(data1);

Comment: Then you'll have to update your question with more details (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696000/after-successful-api-call-back-is-not-properly-called/50696040?noredirect=1#comment88401299_50696000), amongst other things). Debug it, look at the actual value of `data.paid` by stopping the code on a breakpoint and using the web console.

Comment: i have edited with _stripecharge function, and is this the way to use callback